# Flickering with QChartView display

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am running a code on group of images and i have a function "updateGraph" used to plot a line graph to observe the number of cars encountered. I am calling this function for every image to update the graph, but i observe the flickering when graph is updated. I feel it is because i am creating a new widget every time i update the graph. Is there any way update the graph is same widget.?

```
void MainWindow::updateGraph()
{
    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setTitle("Counts");

    QChartView *chartview = new QChartView(chart);
    chartview->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    gridLayout->addWidget(chartview,0,0);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to recreate a new chart every time, you don't even have to take care of the update. Every time you add a point in the series bound to the chart, the chart is already automatically updated.

Comment: Thank you @Fareanor. Do you mean i need to call updateGraph() only for once and rest is updated itself?

Comment: Not exactly, I mean you don't need to call it at all. In your constructor, you create your chart and place it in a chart view (as you did in your function). Then, every time you'll add new series to the chart or update already existing ones, the chart will be updated accordingly.

Comment: You should either declare it as a class member or you can just use the `QChartView::chart()` method to get the chart (assuming you have the chart view as a class member).